# SharePoint Web Part Error

Tags: restore

I am new in SharePoint and I'm tasked to migrate our SharePoint server (SharePoint 2003) to another country. We have successfully restored the SQL DB. But when we start the Sites, there are many Web part Error. I know the programmer (too bad he left long time ago) used kind of 3rd party:

1. EasyTabParts_1.0.0.0__267ad984ab158157_PageTabs.dwp
2. Pentalogic.SharePointReminder.WebPart_1.1.0.0__25aa19a9348bb7bd_Pentalogic.SharePointReminder.dwp

After doing some research, I did these steps:

1. copy some dwp files (EasyTabParts, Pentalogic, etc) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wpcatalog
2. add Safecontrol at `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`

   ```
   <SafeControl Assembly="DocumentLibraryBrowser, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=42f4415f140f5428" Namespace="Stramit.WP" TypeName="*" Safe="True" /> <SafeControl Assembly="MyTreeView, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=42f4415f140f5428" Namespace="FunkeLab" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
   <SafeControl Assembly="SubSites, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2715b3a91cb84b88" Namespace="SubSites" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
   <SafeControl Assembly="EasyTabParts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=267ad984ab158158" Namespace="EasyTabParts" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
   <SafeControl Assembly="Pentalogic.SharePointReminder.WebPart, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=25aa19a9348bb7b8" Namespace="Pentalogic.SharePointReminder" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
   ```
3. reset IIS

But the issue still persists.

Here is the detail error message (see the attached picture as well):

> Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Web Part Page cannot be displayed or imported because it is not registered on this site as safe. [Web Page Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztgLa.jpg)

I also hit the same error when I want to upload the .dwp file. See the picture attached.

[image: .DWP error during import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SP2003, you have 3 things to do to deploy a Web part manually:

1. Add `SafeControl` entries in the web.config
2. Add the .dwp file into C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wpcatalog or in the Web part galery
3. Add the DLL (assembly) into the GAC

You may be missing point #3.: did you add the Web part DLLs in the GAC of the new server? (DocumentLibraryBrowser.dll, MyTreeView.dll, SubSites.dll).

[EDIT]
To add the Web part DLLs:

1. Get the DLLs from the old server. THey're probably located in the GAC (a special folder in `c:\windows\system32\assembly`). As this is a special folder, you can navigate it and copy files only from CMD: from a CMD window, navigate to `c:\windows\system32\assembly\GAC\MSIL\<name of the DLL>\<version>` and copy the DLL file to another location with a `copy` command.
2. On the new server, get the DLL file, and drag/drop it to a Windows Explorer window open on `c:\windows\system32\assembly` (putting a DLL in the GAC is as simple as that).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53417)

Comment: Sorry, I posted the first answer from a phone and during my vacation. And my question was more like an answer in the form of a rhetorical question :). I edited my answer to change the format and add information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Evariste for enlighten me... This issue drives me nuts for weeks.. And you are absolutely right.. I haven't done this step =>" You may be missing point #3.: did you add the Web part DLLs in the GAC of the new server?..." Could you please guide me on how to do this step? Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: I edited my answer to add steps for this.

Comment: Hi Evariste, how I wish you are a lady, so that I can give you a big hug :) :) You did it! You are superbbbb man.. I've been asking around for months but nobody can give me the right answer. 4 thumbs up for you.. :) Thanks a lot once again for solving my issue.. 1 thing I would like to share.. the assembly is located at c:\windows\assembly and not at system32 for my case. And I use this syntax to find out the location of each dll (credit to Sandeep) as not all dll located at GAC[http://snahta.blogspot.sg/2009/01/file-path-for-gac-assemblies.html]
cd C:\windows\Assembly
dir <dllname> /s

Answer (score 2):

Fire up ULS Logger and provide the error message.

Maybe SharePoint UI "hides" the real error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. Do you mind to elaborate more on how can I "Fire up ULS Logger"?

Comment: There's no ULS in SP 2003! 